# Are there identifiers for strings or numbers?

Tags: c++

I recently developed a calculator, this is the code:

```
/*
*All 4 operations + percentage finder + Raise to power and more....
* by Ulisse
* ulissebenedennti@outlook.com
* Feel free to take some parts of this code an put them
* in yours, but do not take all the code and change/delete
* the comments to take the credit, trust me, it doesn't
* gives the satisfaction you expect.
*/

#include <iostream>   //For cin and cout
#include <iomanip>    //For setprecision()
#include <windows.h>  //For SetconsoleTitle()
#include <stdlib.h>   //For system()
#include <cmath>      //For pow()
#include <cctype>     //For isdigit()

using namespace std;

int main(){
    reset:
    system("cls"); //Screen cleaner
    system("color 0f");
    SetConsoleTitle("Calculator                          by Ulisse");//Setting window title
    char op;                //Start of the variables declaration
    double a, b, ra;
    string p, ms, d, me, e;
    p  = " + ";
    ms = " - ";
    d  = " : ";
    me = " x ";
    e  = " = ";             //End of the variable declaration
    cout << "Type now '?' for help page, or another character to continue." << endl;
    cin >> op;
    if (op == '?'){
    help:
    system("cls");
    cout << "Write the whole operation.\nEXAMPLE: 2 ^ 3 \n OUTPUT: 2 ^ 3 = 8"<< endl;
    cout << "(+) Sum between a and b\n(-) Subtraction between a and b" << endl;
    cout << "(^) Raise to power\n(%)finds the a% of b\n(x or *)Multiplicate a by b" << endl;
    cout << "(: or /) Divide a by b" << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    goto start;
    }
    else{
        system("cls");
        while(1){
            start:
            cout << "CALC> ";
            cin >> a;
            cin >> op;
            cin >> b;
            //The four operations
            if (op == '+'){
                cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                cout << setprecision(999) << a << p  << b << e << a + b << endl;
                cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
            }
            if (op == '-'){
                cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                cout << setprecision(999) << a << ms << b << e << a - b << endl;
                cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
            }
            if (op == '*' || op == 'x'){
                cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                cout << setprecision(999) << a << me << b << e << a * b << endl;
                cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
            }
            if (op == '/' || op == ':'){
                cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                cout << setprecision(999) << a << d  << b << e << a / b << endl;
                cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
            }
            if (op == '%'){
                cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                cout << setprecision(999) << "The " << a << "% of " << b << " is " << b / 100 * a << endl;
                cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
            }
            if (op == '^'){
                cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                cout << setprecision(999) << a << " ^ " << b << " = " << pow (a, b) << endl;
                cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
            }
            //Some useful functions
            if (op == 'c'){
                system("cls");
            }
            if (op == '?'){
                system("cls");
                goto help;
            }
            if (op == 'r'){
                goto reset;
            }
            if (op == 'b'){
                system("color 0c");
                Beep(400,500);
                cout << "CLOSING, ARE YOU SURE?(y/n)";
                system("color 0c");
                cin >> op;
                if(op == 'y'){
                    cout << "Closing..." << endl;
                    system("cls");
                    system("color 0f");
                    system("pause");
                    break;
                }
                if(op == 'n'){
                    goto start;
                }
            }
            if (op == '<'){
                if (a < b){
                    cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                    cout << setprecision(999) << a << " < " << b << e << " TRUE " << endl;
                    cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                    cout << setprecision(999) << a << " < " << b << e << " FALSE " << endl;
                    cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
                }
            }
            if (op == '>'){
                if (a > b){
                    cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                    cout << setprecision(999) << a << " > " << b << e << "TRUE" << endl;
                    cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                    cout << setprecision(999) << a << " > " << b << e << "FALSE" << endl;
                    cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
                }
            }
            if (op == '='){
                if (a == b){
                    cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                    cout << setprecision(999) << a << " = " << b << " is TRUE" << endl;
                    cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    cout << "RESULT" << endl;
                    cout << setprecision(999) << a << " = " << b << " is FALSE" << endl;
                    cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it works:
You write a number, then an operator(like +, - plus other functions...) and it makes the operation between the two numbers you typed depending o what is the typed operato, so if you type 4 + 3 it will output 4 + 3 = 7.
Now that you understand how it works, let us go to the qyestion...
Is there an indentifier for a number or a character? When you type a sttring or a character when you cin >> (not a number variable) the application will start printing out characters that you did never inserted:
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0MLa.png)

[I think like this(console output) will be printed out(until you dont close the process.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXTiY.png)

So i would like to prevent the applicatin for failing when you type an invalid input for the variable and making it executes another instruction, here's what i mean:

```
if(anumbervariable != number || anumbervariable == string){
     cout << "invalid input" << endl;
}
```

This isn't a real working code, it's just a representation of what i mean, or i wouldn't came hre to make you waste you lives :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question suffers a bit from a mistaken assumption : when the input doesn't match the variable type, the variable is _not changed_ ! Therefore, you can't test `anumbervariable`. Furthermore, in practice all bits of an **integral** numerical value are used to represent a value. However, there is `std::isnan` for floating-point numbers. This is short for "Is Not a Number".

Comment: You can factor out the "`cout << "RESULT" << endl;`:" from inside your `switch` statement to before the `switch` statement since it occurs in each case.

Comment: Do you really want 999 for `setprecision`?  You may want to use the numerical limits from [this example in CppReference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: I recommend studying [calculator examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+calculator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) already posted on StackOverflow.  I believe yours is overly complicated.

Comment: The generally used  division character for computers is '/' not ':'.  Check out some of the existing calculator applications.  (Also look at the math operators for C and C++ languages).

Comment: The `#include` should be `#include <cstdlib>` not `stdlib.h`.

Comment: I recommend using the `switch` statement rather than an `if` ladder.

Comment: I recall reading some SO discussion about how speed increases at 22 switch statements and anything under that is rewritten as an if?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like follows

```
int getNumber(){
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    while(cin.fail()){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        cout << "invalid input"<<endl;
        cin >> x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

If you want to do a character by character thing, C++ has an isalpha() function, so you can use !isalpha(). The numeric limits thing is the max buffer that can be taken before a new line. If you print it out, it's just some large number so that it can ignore that amount of input.

Comment: @LogicStuff What's happening

Comment: I made an edit and took it back. I should have just proposed it.